# Why does PostgreSQL create an additional NULL bitmap if all fields after the 8th are NOT NULL?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, null

I don't refer to the 1 Byte null bitmap included in the row header that could be used to  flag null values for any of the first 8 columns. See:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145772/do-nullable-columns-occupy-additional-space-in-postgresql/12147130#12147130

My question is about the new 8 bytes null bitmap added by Postgresql to each row:

- with 9 or more columns
- and including at least one null

I have done some tests by creating / populating some tables and checking row size using `pgstattuple` extension and I have observed this strange behavior.

**The new null bitmap is created** even if the 9th (and last) column is created with `NOT NULL` constraint.

Do you have any explanations? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: The OP mentioned the *1* byte null bitmap for up to 8 user columns (not 2 bytes). I ran extensive tests in the past and studied the source code, and I can confirm that is correct. Nullable or not is irrelevant, though, and that's the point here.

Comment: @ypercube : I didn't know how the additional bytes were added in the row storage. ErwinBrandstetter gives the answer below : the initial null bitmap is extended. So I was wrong. My tests were only about total row size, not storage order details.

Comment: Thnx, that's why I asked. The question was not clear on how you performed and tests and how you arrived into a conclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is also in [the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008753/does-not-using-null-in-postgresql-still-use-a-null-bitmap-in-the-header/7383198#7383198):

> `NOT NULL` constraints do not directly affect that.

The size of the NULL bitmap is not influenced by `NOT NULL` constraints *at all*.

And there is only ever *one* (or no) NULL bitmap per row. Never an *"additional"* NULL bitmap. For rows up to 8 user columns the spare byte between row header and column data (or an optional OID) is used. With more than 8 user columns, the NULL bitmap is *extended* by `MAXALIGN` (typically 8 bytes). Column data moves back by the same number of bytes. Resulting in a *single* NULL bitmap.

Even if it might seem reasonable not to extend the bitmap for trailing columns with `NOT NULL` constraints, complications might ensue. Like: removing a constraint would have to trigger a whole-table rewrite.

And even if that might be handled, I expect no core developer would be willing to complicate the code to save a few bytes per row for this rare special case.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought was going, too. So if the table has 9 to 16 columns, the null map is extended to 2 bytes. If 17-24 to 3 bytes, etc. Correct? (unless MAXALIGN is different)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter : thank you for the precision. I have seen the reason, but I didn't understand why. And your explanation is perfectly right : having to rewrite the whole table for any NOT NULL constraint removal is too high cost.

Comment: @ypercube : since a 9th column is added, the null bitmap is extended by MAXALIGN (typically 8) bytes. So it can handle up to 64 more columns. And again since a 73th column is added ...

Comment: @mnementh64: Exactly right.